# sqlserver restoring database takes 15 minutes and going!

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm just restoring a small database(-5MB) but it is taking a lot of time?
Is it standard or darkness is a feature?

Comment: answer for other people:the best way to restore is deleting the database before restore.then it takes 5 secs.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on where it's restoring from.  If you're taking it from tape, even the smallest file will need seek time, which depending on the tape drive could be a substantial multiple of the actual restore time needed.  A restore job may also require to index and/or catalog the restore media.

Comment: solved just few seconds ago.and it was restoring from the c:\program files\....\MSSQL\....bak

Answer (score 0):

Takes way too long. Anything funny in the logs? 5 mb should take seconds - lets say a minute, maximum. That is MAXIMUM in HUGH letters. Unless you have a 300gb log file that needs processing after restoring the database.

Comment: it is still restoring.help!!!that is important data.

Comment: the log is about 700MB.but the database was cleared before the time i am trying to restore.

Comment: 700mb log on a 5mb database- can take some time, especially if... well... the disc subsystem is "workstation quality". You ahve tons of disc activity?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "with stats = 1" to your restore clause so you can see some movement.  My guess is the log file being created is the issue, you could switch the db recovery mode to simple mode and shrink the log down (don't tell Paul Randall) so it's less to allocate.